# how to update an object, instantiate in the constructor, after an ajax call?

Tags: php, ajax, symfony

I just want to know if it is possible to instantiate an object (or a service) in a constructor controller and update this object with differents ajax call.

First, the injection in my controller works fine, I already try to do that with session or cookie, but in reality myObj is more complex than one number to increment, so it doesn't seem to be what I need.

```php
class MyController extends Controller
{

    private $myObj;

    public function __construct(MyObj $myObj)
    {

        $this->myObj = $myObj;
    }


    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {

        $aData['pageTitle'] = 'exemple';
        $aData['pageSubtitle'] = 'on stackoverflow';

        return $this->render('Bundle:page.html.twig', $aData);

    }

    public function ajaxAction(Request $request){

        $this->myObj->increment_nbDomain();
        return new JsonResponse('ok');
    }

}
```

My object

```php
class myObj
{
    public $nbDomain = 0;

    public function increment_nbDomain(){
        $this->nbDomain++;
    }

}
```

The jQuery function

```
$('.buttonPlus').on('click', function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '{{ path('route_to_ajaxAction') }}',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

nbDomain is always equal to zero

Comment: Basically no.  What you are really asking is can I keep an object between requests?  In php every request starts from ground zero which means you will get a new $myObj for each request.  You will need to persist the state of $myObj (either in a session or maybe a database) and then rehydrate it for each request.  I might point out that you can store objects in the session (even complex ones) if that is what you need to do.  Just a question of serialization.

Comment: Thanks, that what I was thinking